# System.InvalidOperationException: A specified Include path is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to get a list of projects on the index page - but I keep on getting errors. I have tried different codes, and below is the latest one I've tried - but it's still not working. It gave me this error:

System.InvalidOperationException: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'StoreWeb.Models.Project' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Collections'

I think it's because I don't know how to get collectionID from the Project table. For the Project table, it has collectionID is as a foreign key. (A project must have 1 collection. A collection may have projects.)

Can someone please help me? Here's what I have:

**MODELS**

---

Collection.cs [Modified]

---

```
[Table("Collection")]
public class Collection
{
    [Key]
    public string collectionID { get; set; }
    public string collectionName { get; set; }

    public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

---

Project.cs [Modified]

---

```
[Table("Project")]
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public string projectID { get; set; }
    public string projectName { get; set; }
    public string projectCity { get; set; }
    public string collectionID { get; set; } // This is what was needed!

    public virtual Collection Collection { get; set; }
}
```

For the class Project, it has collectionID is as a foreign key. (A project must have 1 collection. A collection may have projects.)

---

ProductEntities.cs

---

```
public class ProductEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Collection> Collections { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project>    Projects  { get; set; }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

---

ProjectController [Modified]

---

```
using System.Data.Entity;

public class ProjectController : Controller
{
    ProductEntities productDB = new ProductEntities();

    //
    // GET: /Project/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var projectModel = productDB.Projects.Include(m => m.Collection);
        return View(projectModel);
    }
```

**VIEWS**

---

Views/Project/Index.chtml

---

```
@model IEnumerable<StoreWeb.Models.Project>

@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h1>PROJECTS</h1>

     @foreach (var project in Model)
     {
         <br /><a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id = project.projectID })">@project.projectName</a> 
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a typo

```
public ActionResult Index(string project)
    {
        var projectModel = productDB.Projects.Include("Collection");
        return View(projectModel);
    }
```

and not "Collections"

**TIP (of the day)**

in your usings, add

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

and then you can make

```
var projectModel = productDB.Projects.Include(m => m.Collection);
```

you'll avoid "string" typos.

**EDIT**

for your classes, if you're using code First (which you are)

remove the "ForeignKeys"  (collection_id in Project, for example), and just do

```
//remove the "Bind Exclude"
public class Collection
{
    public int Id { get; set; }//make it int, it will be taken as the primary key
    public string collectionName { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Project> Projects { get; set; }//make it virtual, lazy loading inside
}
```

in your project  class

```
//remove any "collection_Id" property
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }//make it it, rename it, it will be taken as PK
    public string projectName { get; set; }
    public string projectCity { get; set; }

    public virtual Collection Collection { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Raphaël. I've tried both of your suggestions, but both of them gave me this error instead: ::: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Collection_collectionID' :::  (There's a column name "collectionID" in both the Project and Collection tables.) Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Is there a way for me to use string as a data type for PK (b/c the PKs for both Project and Collection have a mix of letters and numbers)?

Comment: yes, just put `[Key]` attribute on Id (in my example) in your table definition : I think (maybe wrong), that EF recognizes automatically Id or `<TableName>Id` only if it's an int.

Comment: For ex, did you mean like this?::: 
        [Key] public string projectID { get; set; }
::: If so, I've tried edited both tables, but it still gave me the same error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Collection_collectionID'  [Add't info -- On the error page, it says that the Source Error is: @foreach (var project in Model) ] So, maybe that's what I need to change? But I know know how...

Comment: Could you please edit your first post and show your 2 classes complete and "modified"  ?

Comment: Yes, I've modified everything as you suggested.

Comment: I've got it now! All I needed left to do was add ::: public string collectionID { get; set; } ::: to the Project class. Thank you again for your help, Raphaël!

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: FOR EF CORE 3+ or 5+:**

I know this has been answered but I faced similar issue using EF Core when reverse engineering or scaffolding a database:

This issue came up with include property on the indexes in my DbContext, when I have multiple properties involved in the Indexes.

**After reverse engineering or Scaffolding from DB inside my OnModelCreating method I had this:**

```
entity.HasIndex(e => e.BusinessName, "NonClusteredIndex-20190824-150740")
                 .IncludeProperties(new[] { "Contentid", "Stateid", "Cityid", "businessurl", "UserID" });
```

**Then I changed it to this**

```
entity.HasIndex(e => e.BusinessName, "NonClusteredIndex-20190824-150740")
                 .IncludeProperties(bmaster => new { bmaster.Contentid, bmaster.Stateid, bmaster.Cityid, bmaster.Businessurl, bmaster.UserId });
```

This resolved for me. In this case, EF Core couldn't use the string parameters, I hope this will be fixed in the new release of EF Core.